Men covering their heads in Catholic churches?
Are Christian (Catholic) men allowed to cover their head? I've told no they can't, because Paul said not too, or some say yes, because Jesus himself did, and what Paul says didn't matter, but if a man is praying in private can he not cover his head? Wouldn't it be respectful for a man to cover his head in the presence of God and follow the ways of Jesus?

Men head covering in Catholic Churches?
While it is customary for men not to wear head coverings in Catholic churches, there exists a few exceptions. Popes, bishops and abbots wear zucchettos and mitres when officiating at solemn masses. Many priests still wear the biretta at mass and vespers. It should be understood that during the consecration no head wear is permitted and all popes, bishops and abbots and priests must be bare headed for the prayer of consecration at mass.
It is not uncommon for Benedictine monks to wear their hoods while praying the Divine Office in churches that are extremely cold. This is true of both traditional (Old Rite) and New Rite Religious.
Infirm male religious may be permitted to wear a skullcap in church due to health reasons. They are generally solid black and resemble a Jewish Kippah.

Generally speaking headgear for men in Catholic churches is deemed inappropriate and frowned upon.
I have seen men suffering cancer treatment and wear a skullcap at mass. Once we understand the ecclesiastical customs and traditions, such exemptions seems quite reasonable and are in keeping with the dignity and decorum asked for by Catholic tradition.
It was mandated in the 1917 Code of Canon Law. Canon 1262 states:


It is desirable that, consistent with ancient discipline, women be separated from men in church.

Men, in a church or outside a church, while they are assisting at sacred rites, shall be bare-headed, unless the approved mores of the people or peculiar circumstances of things determine otherwise; women, however, shall have a covered head and be modestly dressed, especially when they approach the table of the Lord.



The new code of Canon Law has nothing on this issue yet common ecclesiastical customs and traditions still prevail in this matter.
To be honest with you, baseball hats at church are not appropriate!
